# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \begin{figure}[h]

Tags: graphics, stack

I have found similar errors posted but none related to the figure command. I am trying to show a figure in my Latex template, if I remove the `\begin{figure}[h]` block, my file runs OK, but currently I cannot show any figure. The files I have are:

Main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,PhD,twoside]{muthesis}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecafterpnum{\vskip\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\school{School name}
\faculty{Faculty}
\def\wordcount{xxxxx}    

\beforeabstract
\input{abstract}
\afterabstract
\prefacesection{Acknowledgements}
\afterpreface

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapter1}
\chapter{Background}    
\chapter{Conclusions}    

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{ANO} A.N.~Other, ....
\end{thebibliography}    

\appendix
\chapter{A Long Proof}

\end{document}
```

abstract.tex

```
\begin{singlespace}
    This is the abstract.
\end{singlespace}
```

chapter 1.tex

```
This is a ref to Figure 1 below. 

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{figure1}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}
```

Other errors:

chapter1 - TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \begin{figure}[h]

abstract - Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph

chapter 1 - Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

The errors above disappear if I remove the `\begin{figure}[h]` block but I need to put figures.

Thank you for any help.

The class I am using is [here](http://www.cl.eps.manchester.ac.uk/medialand/maths/LaTeX/muthesis.cls).

Comment: The files are shown there :) Files are "chapter1" and "abstract"

Comment: If you copy and past the files as they are shown there. The error appears. The contents shown in chpater1.tex and abstract.tex is all I have inside those.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit to include the class file which is the only missing thing

Comment: oh that is a different muthesis to the one in texlive (look at line 25:-):-)

Comment: If I add `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your MWE and change the line `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}` to `\PassOptionsToPackage{doublespacing}{setspace}` and finally change `figure1` to `example-image-duck` I can compile your MWE without any error.

Comment: Ok, if I use the cls from your link I get the same error.

Comment: the one in texlive was edited by Graham 2011 `%% Time-stamp: <2011-08-25 16:41:19 grahamgough>`   The one you are using is dated 2013 but based on an ancient version of Graham's `%% Time-stamp: <July 23, 1997 11:33:00 BST graham@zzzzz>` and seems to be basically broken.  I would use the muthesis that is in texlive and add graphicx package and hyperref.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I changed the class and it works fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one in texlive was edited by Graham 2011

```
%% Time-stamp: <2011-08-25 16:41:19 grahamgough>
```

The one you are using is dated 2013 but based on an ancient version of Graham's

```
%% Time-stamp: <July 23, 1997 11:33:00 BST graham@zzzzz>
```

and seems to be basically broken. I would use the `muthesis.cls` that is in texlive and add `graphicx` package and `hyperref` in your preamble.